# Using repositories as Hosting service

Tags: git, web-applications, hosting, repository

Is it possible to use the version control repositories like github or bitbucket as hosting service for your website? Because i know lot of companies have different domain for testing their website in different stages such as development, master, testing, production etc., as **stage.domain.com**. So how they are doing like that? Are they hosting their files into some hosting service at each stage for testing? I'm little confused on this. Sorry if this question is too idiotic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some services/softwares doing this things for us. Here is a article by CHRIS COYIER of css-tricks. After trying some free deploying services i personally recommend **deployhq.com** for this purpose. They are really doing very good job for free.

Answer (score 1):

The way its usually done is that you give your server pull permission for different branches of your project. For example you might have a development and deployment branch.

On your test server you would keep pulling from your development branch and when everything is finally ready for deployment you have your main server pull from the deployment branch once you have committed your code.

So the the server it self is not being hosted on github or bitbucket but the code is always being updated there and the server can update from it on the fly.